# How can I determine when a draggable is over a droppable that won't accept it?

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a collection of draggable elements, each of which can  be dropped on droppable elements. Some draggables are not accepted by some droppables, and I express this with the `accept` callback. When a drop is not accepted, I show this by changing the color of the droppable

The reason a draggable is rejected may not be obvious, so I'd like to be more explicit and show a message explaining the rejection. But I cannot find a way to do this, because the `over` event never fires if the drop isn't accepted.

How could I detect a drag over an *unacceptable* drop target, so that I could show a message at that location indicating the reason for the non-acceptance?